# Merge PDF Files using python PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have watched a video to learn how to merge PDF files into one PDF file. I tried to modify a little in the code so as to deal with a folder which has the PDF files
The main folder (Spyder) has the `Demo.py` and this is the code

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

source_dir = os.getcwd() + './PDF Files'
merger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.endswith('pdf'):
        merger.append(item)

merger.write('.PDF Files/Output/Complete.pdf')       
merger.close()
```

I have a subfolder named `PDF Files` into the main folder `Spyder` and in this subfolder I put the PDF files and inside the subfolder `PDF Files` I created a folder named `Output`.
I got error file not found as for the 1.pdf although when printing the `item` inside the loop, I got the PDF names.

The Traceback of error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 9, in <module>
    merger.append(item)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 114, in merge
    fileobj = file(fileobj, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.pdf'
```

Comment: Please add the full backtrace from the error to your question.

Answer (score 7):

I could solve it like that

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

source_dir = './PDF Files/'
merger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.endswith('pdf'):
        #print(item)
        merger.append(source_dir + item)

merger.write(source_dir + 'Output/Complete.pdf')       
merger.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Shorter, faster stronger!

```
import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

merger = PdfMerger()

for file in glob.glob('PDF_Folder/*.pdf'):
    merger.append(file)

merger.write('Complete.pdf')       
merger.close()
```